# error when check email and password on nodeJs mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

i have a logical error idk where exactly, i think my query is wrong, i have this code (nodejs):

```
router.post('/compteCon', (req, res)=>{
    console.log('CONNECTION OF AN ACCOUNT');
    const email = req.body.email;
    const MotPasse = req.body.MotPasse;
    console.log(email + ' '+ MotPasse)
    const sql = 'select * from compte where (compte.email = \"'+email+'\" and \"'+MotPasse+'\"=compte.MotPasse1)'
    getConn().query(sql,(err, results)=>{
        if(err){
            console.log('failed Connect to account : ', err)
            res.sendStatus(500)  
            return
        }
        if(results[0] == null){
            console.log("Your Email or Password is wrong");
            res.end();
        }else{
            console.log(results[0]);
            res.end();
        }
    })
    res.redirect('next.html')
    res.end();
})
```

the result shown when i submit the POST form connection **with an account exist in my database** is:

```
server running port is 3000
CONNECTION OF AN ACCOUNT
undefined undefined
::1 - - [30/Aug/2022:14:06:01 +0000] "POST /compteCon HTTP/1.1" 302 62 "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Your Email or Password is wrong
```

**look at the last sentence result**!!

i have on index.html this button (bootstrap styling!)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success rounded submit px-3" id="submitBtn">Login</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you hash the password before storing it on the database, like you should have?

Comment: @RiggsFolly no, ofc i ll do that

Comment: Start with a little bit of debugging. console.log the values you are using for `email` and `MotPasse` and the content of `sql` that may point you in the right direction Then check you actually have a user with those 2 values that match on your DB

Comment: Also you can try running the query, once you output it in phpmyadmin of something like that to prove it works

Comment: console.log(email + ' '+ MotPasse)  show me two undefined

Comment: look i use on the same compte.js file two router.post(...) its normal?

Comment: Then there is your problem, work out where those values should be collected from as it seems `req.body.email` and `req.body.MOTPasse` is not where those values are stored

Comment: i find where is the error, it return error when i put the submit button between <div class="form-group"></div> bootstrap form. than <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success rounded submit px-3" id="submitBtn">Login</button> only send data on POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like nothings actually being passed as shown when the console says: undefined undefined. So it most likely isn't your query rather the fact that it has nothing to actually work with. Maybe, the frontend isn't passing the required data to the backend, just keep trying to debug, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I remove this **div**:

```
<div class="form-group"></div>
```

And now only:

```
<button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-success rounded submit px-3" id="submitBtn">Login</button>
```